# Java threading error

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am trying to make a thread using the "implements runnable" method. However Java is complaining of the lack of a constructor. What is a a good way to handle this?
This is the error in question.

```
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\src\EntityClientPlayerMP.java:49: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor EntityClientPlayerMP()
location: class net.minecraft.src.EntityClientPlayerMP
         Runnable runnable = new EntityClientPlayerMP();
                             ^
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to `EntityClientPlayerMP` please?

Comment: Are you sure that EntityClientPlayerMP has a constructor, and if it does, if it takes no parameters? Please show us the results of your efforts. You shouldn't be asking here before searching for this information, and if you've searched for it, you should show us the results. Sorry, but this is not a very well crafted question.

Comment: umm. Its in the Minecraft SRC go decompile it using MCP.

Comment: @jtl999: I suggest you are more polite to the people who are giving their personal time to help you. The onus is on you to provide sufficient information for your problem to be solved.

Comment: What constructors do you have in the class?  If you have one that takes parameters, but not one that does not, the default (no-parameter) constructor is not generated, and therefore you will not have one to call without parameters available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search online reveals that the `EntityClientPlayerMP` has a [constructor](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/files/jd124/client/net/minecraft/src/EntityClientPlayerMP.html#EntityClientPlayerMP%28net.minecraft.client.Minecraft,%20net.minecraft.src.World,%20net.minecraft.src.Session,%20net.minecraft.src.NetClientHandler%29):

```
EntityClientPlayerMP(Minecraft par1Minecraft, World par2World,
    Session par3Session, NetClientHandler par4NetClientHandler)
```

Since that is the only constructor, creating a new object of that class will require you call it with that.